# Symfony2 TwitterBundle Security

Tags: php, security, twitter, symfony

I am trying to integrate [TwitterBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/TwitterBundle) into my simple application to allow users to login via Twitter. I cannot find any documentation on how to integrate this into the security component to facilitate this. I have the Twitter button displaying fine, but when clicked it changes to connected, however I still remain an anonymous user.

Any tips or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks